# Browser getting confused with similar-named directories?

Tags: http, files

This might be completely off-topic, and if so, I'm sorry, but it's about servers and it's got me completely baffled.

Basically, seemingly at random, images get loaded wrong. It's never happened to me, and it's completely unpredictable, which makes it all the harder to diagnose.

But it seems like, occasionally, the browser (or server) gets mixed up over which file to send.

In the most recent case, the image that should have been loaded was:

```
/img/sprites/c/f/a.png
```

But the image that was actually loaded was:

```
/img/sprites/f/c/a.png
```

The browser then caches this image, which is the wrong one, and the user has to Ctrl+F5 to get the image to load properly.

I've noticed that this seems to always occur with sprites of a similar filename - on an older project of mine, it would occasionally be the case that this would happen:

```
Should be: /img/sprites/p_m/123.png
Actually : /img/sprites/p_ms/123.png
```

My initial thought was mod_speling, but this module is not installed on my server.

Is this something you have encountered? Any advice on what might possibly be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using Apache? Are the images transferred directly or loaded from some script? Can you correlate this with log file entries?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Apache. Images are transferred directly. I can't seem to find any relevant log file entries - it doesn't help that the site is highly active so there's a lot of logs.

Comment: Was p_ms renamed to p_m at some point? Maybe an old, cached version of the source?

Comment: @iPaulo Nope, it's always been that way.

Comment: Where exactly do these URLs to images exist? In HTML, CSS? Is it dynamically generated or static?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about the environment, config and source of the pages, the answer has to be pretty generic.

**Simplify** to make the problem more reproducible.

Also, gather as much information as you can. If you use google analytics or google webmaster tools, look there for clues. Look at the pages with Chrome's developer tools or something like Firebug.

Comment: The problem with this is that it relies on reproducibility. There is none here. It is completely random, and with tends of thousands of users it only happens once or twice every month or so, roughly. With odds like that... well, there's not really much I can do to investigate like this.